# How can I send any text via triggered email button in bold font? So that It gets display in email in bold Font

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

So I am working on powerapps. I triggered the email when a button is clicked in powerapps. I want the text of checkbox selected to be bold when it gets displayed in email.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? Is it how to get the text of the selected checkbox? Or how to bold portions of an email?

Answer (score 0):

When you send an e-mail using the Outlook.com or the Office 365 Outlook connectors, you can use HTML as the format for the e-mail body, so if you wrap any text in the e-mail with `<b>...</b>` tags (or using styles, or other similar tags), you can make the text be bold.

For example, in this app below, I can send an e-mail with the options in bold using an expression like the following for the button's OnSelect property:

```
'Outlook.com'.SendEmailV2(
    txtEmail.Text,
    txtSubject.Text,
    "<h2>Options selected:</h2>" &
        If(chkOption1.Value, "<li><b>" & chkOption1.Text & "</b></li>", "") &
        If(chkOption2.Value, "<li><b>" & chkOption2.Text & "</b></li>", "") &
        If(chkOption3.Value, "<li><b>" & chkOption3.Text & "</b></li>", ""))
```

[image: App with controls for e-mail address, subject and checkboxes]